# How to add a driver to a single component of a vector with Python script?

Tags: python, drivers

When using Python to add a driver to a vector, i.e. the constant offset of an array modifier, it adds drivers to all three components while I only need to drive one of them.

Is there a way to add a driver to only one component, or perhaps to add drivers to all three and then delete the unnecessary two?

Here's how I add the driver:

```
arr_mod = active_object.modifiers.new("Array", 'ARRAY')
fcurves = arr_mod.driver_add('constant_offset_displace')
```

Comment: Post a minified code snippet showing your problem - the fix is simple you need to define which channel to drive…

Comment: Thanks Markus. I've updated my question with a code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an updated snippet that adds a driver only to the $y$ component of the constant offset:

```py
from bpy import context as C

arr_mod = C.object.modifiers.new("Array", 'ARRAY')
arr_mod.use_constant_offset = True
fcurves = arr_mod.driver_add('constant_offset_displace', 1)
```

Probably needless to say, the $xyz$ components have $0, 1, 2$ indices in that order.

When writing the code in the Python Console, you can hit <kbd>⭾ Tab</kbd> after opening parenthesis of `driver_add(` to see hints on how to use it:

[image]

Comment: Wow! So simple.
Thanks a lot Markus, that's a great answer!